# Make a select field disabled with a preselected value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, disabled-input

I want to be able to achieve the same thing on the City select field. I want the city to be like the country field with just a normal text or given value that cannot be changed.

[image: what i'm trying to achieve]

Below is my code for the state for woocommerce fields in my function.php. what type should i use?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {  

    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['options'] = array('Auckland' => 'Auckland');


    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a field **read only** *(disabled)* in checkout page *(and also in My account > Adresses > Billing Address section)*…

2 different cases:

**1) For a `select` type**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_checkout_billing_city_field', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_billing_city_field( $billing_fields ) {
    // HERE define the city
    $city = 'Auckland';

    // Set the city value (to be sure)
    WC()->customer->set_billing_city( $city );

    // Change the billing city field
    $billing_fields['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
    $billing_fields['billing_city']['options'] = array( $city => $city );
    $billing_fields['billing_city']['default'] = $city;
    $billing_fields['billing_city']['custom_attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';

    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

The select field is disabled *(read only)* with the preselected city:

[image]

---

**2) For a `text` type**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_checkout_billing_city_field', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_billing_city_field( $billing_fields ) {
    // HERE define the city
    $city = 'Auckland';

    // Set the city value (to be sure)
    WC()->customer->set_billing_city( $city );

    // Change the billing city field
    $billing_fields['billing_city']['default'] = $city;
    $billing_fields['billing_city']['custom_attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';

    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

The text field is read only with the preselected city:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late response I just added this to my function.php file and it worked perfectly thank you.